# what have i done wrong with my python "guess the number" game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
attempts = 0
guess = 5 
name = input("what is your name?: ")
print("Hello",name,"i am thinking of a number")
print("it is between 1-20")
user_Guess = int(input("can you guess what it is?: "))
while user_Guess <5:
   print("Too low!")
attempts += 1
while user_Guess >5:
   print("too high!")
attempts += 1
```

im using the latest  version of python and i don't know where i have went wrong. When i type in the correct answer "5" it prints that its too low!!!! what do i do?!please help if you can but don't over complicate or drastically change my answer.

Comment: I just ran this. You will  get an infinite loop out of anything that isn't 5, but then if I enter 5 it doesn't do anything (as expected?). Are you sure that that's your code?

Comment: yes thats my problem

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard

Comment: you specifically wrote that inputting 5 results in "too low". The code you shared here can never ever do that.

Comment: erm then im not sure where i have went wrong @yuvi

Comment: is there any way possible you could help me? @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so first things first, if you want a cleaner solved version I made one. Don't check it out before you try yourself though, but keep the link: https://repl.it/EQOg/2

Your current code doesn't do anything if you give it 5. No reason for a "Too Low" message.

However, if you try anything that isn't (including numbers beyond 20) you will get an infinite loop, because there's no opportunity for the user to fix anything. See the code runs one line after the other, so say if I guess 3, than this loop:

```
while user_Guess <5:
   print("Too low!")
```

Will go on forever, since user_Guess will *always* be lower than 5. What you want to do is have **only one** `while` loop, that will break when the user guessed correctly. General tip, when you try to build something logical like this, it's helpful to write pseudo code describing what you're trying to achieve. In this case, you probably want something like this:

```
#take number input from user
while users guess is wrong:

    if the number is higher:
        # print something & count attempt
    if the number is lower:
        # print something & count attempt
    if the number is invalid:
        # print something

    # take number input from user (again)
    ## this is the important part - it lets the user change his guess. 
    ## If his guess is correct, it will break the loop. 
    ## If not, he gets to try again and again until correct

# print some success message after breaking the loop
```

There are more clever designs but this is the simplest I think

- P.S.: *Note that my linked solution doesn't fix an invalid input (i.e. input that isn't a number). You should validate that yourself as well*

Comment: @samanthadays you're welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as correct if you found it helpful